# Abstract product of disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am having a little difficulty with what is seemingly a simple exercise, I must show that in a permutation group $S_{n}$ where $\sigma = (p_1  p_2  ...  p_n)$ is a k-cycle and $i<j$ that $(p_i p_j) \sigma $ is a product of two disjoint cycles.

I am not sure how to approach this, can I simply rewrite as $(1 \space 2 \space 3 ... p_i)(p_j, p_k)$? 
Or have I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For all $\tau\in S_n$, $\tau(p_1\cdots p_n)\tau^{-1}=(\tau(p_1)\cdots\tau(p_n))$.

What do you get with $\tau=(p_i p_j)$?

Comment: $(p_i p_j p_1)$ and so on? But wait, what about the inverse?

Comment: @user No, you're calculating it wrong! For example, if $\sigma=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)$, $i=3$ and $j=5$, we get $\tau=(3\ 5)$, and $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(1\ 2\ 5\ 4\ 3)$, by what I stated.

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand

Comment: @user By the hint I provided, if $\tau=(p_i\ p_j)$ then $\rho\overset{def}{=}\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ is a cycle, so $\tau\sigma=\rho\tau$ is a product of two cycles ($\rho$ and $\tau$). But it seems you don't understand how cycle notation works, so you should really review it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation

Comment: Okay, I finally got it, your right, I was messing up the cyclic multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true that composing a cyclic permutation $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k)$  with a transposition $(p_i,p_j)$ will give a product of two disjoint cycles if $p_i$ and $p_j$ occur in the cyclic permutation. For example, it can be verified that $(p_1,\ldots,p_i,p_{i+1},\ldots,p_j,\ldots,p_k)(p_i,p_j)$ $= (p_1,\ldots,p_{i-1}, p_j, \ldots, p_k)(p_i,p_{i+1},\ldots, p_{j-1})$.

More generally, composing a permutation with a transposition either increases or decreases the number of disjoint cycles by $1$.  If the two points in the transposition occur in the same cycle of the permutation, composing will split up this cycle into two disjoint cycles.  If the two points in the transposition occur in different cycles of the permutation, composing will combine the two disjoint cycles into a single cycle.